# Objeto Produto Salva na primeira tela mas na segunda não

Tags: android, sqlite

Olá, estou tendo um problema com um projetinho de estudos.
Tenho 2 activitys, Primeiro Produto e Segundo Produto.

A primeira instancia o objeto Produto1 e salva ele no banco SQLite, quando chama a segunda activity ele passa o id do produto que acabou de salvo através do put.

Na segunda Activity, Produto2 ele recupera o ID do banco e salva um segundo produto.

O problema é que ele salva o primeiro produto e salva o segundo mas se olharmos dentro do banco o segundo so foi com o id, resto das informações que são importantes não ficam salvas.

Ja verifiquei as referencias dentro do Layout_Segundo_Produto.xml, ja verifiquei o objeto Produto que recebeu as informações da tela do XML. Esta tudo ok.

Segue imagem do SQLite Expert:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ProdutoDAO

```
package produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.DAO;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.Model.Produto;

/**
 * Created by Hugo on 24/06/2015.
 */
public class ProdutoDAO {

    //TODO declarando objeto
    //Objeto databaseHelper da Classe do mesmo nome que auxilia no gerenciamento do banco
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    // Banco de dados
    private SQLiteDatabase comparedatabase;


    //Constructor que recebe o contexto e instancia o DatabaseHelper()
    public ProdutoDAO(Context ctx){
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }

    //TODO: sad
    // M�todo que verifica se o banco esta vazio, caso esteja vazio ele abre o banco.
    private SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
    if (comparedatabase == null){
        comparedatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return comparedatabase;
    }

    //Recupera de um cursor dados que vieram de um banco por exemplo para Incstanciar um Produto que
    //podera ser trabalhado como Model (Objeto VO, POJO por exemplo)
    private Produto criarProduto(Cursor cursor){
    Produto produto = new Produto(
            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._Produto.ID_PROD)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._Produto.UNIDADE)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._Produto.DESCRICAO)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._Produto.QUANTIDADE)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._Produto.PRECO))
    );

    return produto;
    }


    /*      M�todo de insert dentro do banco de dados. Ele recebe como parametro um objeto do
    tipo produto que veio da aplica��o (Activity por exemplo) aonde esta trabalhando com o objeto DAO
    */
    public boolean salvarProduto(Produto produto) {
    //ContentValue que sera usado para passar como parametro nos m�todos update ou insert do banco de dados
    ContentValues ctv = new ContentValues();
    ctv.put(DatabaseHelper._Produto.UNIDADE.toString(), produto.getUnidade().toString());
    ctv.put(DatabaseHelper._Produto.DESCRICAO, produto.getDesricao());
    ctv.put(DatabaseHelper._Produto.QUANTIDADE.toString(), produto.getQuantidade());
    ctv.put(DatabaseHelper._Produto.PRECO.toString(), produto.getPreco());

    //Caso o produto que foi passado como parametro para o metodo salvarProduto() seja diferente de NULL
    // ou seja, existe um id, ou seja, ele esta tentando atualizar algo que ja existe ele chama o metodo .update()
    if(produto.getId_prod() != null){
        return getDatabase().update(DatabaseHelper._Produto.TABELA, ctv, "id_prod=?", new String[]{produto.getId_prod().toString()})>0;
    }

    // Caso contario , se o id for null ele insere os dados
    return getDatabase().insert(DatabaseHelper._Produto.TABELA, null, ctv)>0;
    }

    public boolean removerProduto(Produto produto){
    return getDatabase().delete(DatabaseHelper._Produto.TABELA, "id_prod", new String[]{produto.getId_prod().toString()})>0;
    }

    public Produto buscarProdutobyID(Integer id){
    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper._Produto.TABELA, DatabaseHelper._Produto.COLUNAS, "id_prod=?", new String[]{id.toString()}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Produto produtomodel = criarProduto(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return produtomodel;
    }
        return null;
    }

    public Integer ultimoProduto(){
    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper._Produto.TABELA, DatabaseHelper._Produto.COLUNAS, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToLast()){
        Produto produtomodel = criarProduto(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return produtomodel.getId_prod();
    }
    return null;
    }


    //M�todo que vai retornar uma LISTA de produtos
    public List<Produto> produtoAll(){
    //   Sempre quando tivermos algo como uma lista ou um resultado fatalmente precisaremos de
    // um CURSOR para percorrer os resultados e montar ou apresentar esse reultado depois
    // O cursor precisa de ser instanciado com um banco de dados e algum m�todo do banco de dados como uma query,
    // nesse caso foi criado um outro m�todo getDatabase() que esta acima verifica se o banco n�o esta
    // vazio, caso esteja o banco � aberto com o m�todo getWritableDatabase() e retorne um objeto do tipo SQliteDatabase
    // a Query precisa dos parametros para fazer a consulta no banco que s�o:
    /*/ query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
            String orderBy)*/
    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper._Produto.TABELA, DatabaseHelper._Produto.COLUNAS,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    //A lista de produtos que sera de fato retornada pelo m�todo produtoALL()
    //Essa lista 'produtos' logo a frente vai receber pelo m�todo .add cada produto que existe no cursosr quando passar
    //pelo While caso seja possivel (se existir) mover para o proximo item do cursos.
    List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();

    //While que passa por cada item do cursor. Enquanto existir itens para serem movidor ele move para o pr�ximo com o
    //m�todo moveToNext() que � um m�todo da Classe Cursor como podemos ver logo abaixo.
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        //Cada passada pelo cursor dentro do While ele cria um novo objeto produto e insere com o .add dentro da lista
        //de produtos
        Produto produto = criarProduto(cursor);
        produtos.add(produto);
    }

    //Retorna a lista de produtos
    return produtos;
    }






    public void fecharDB(){
    databaseHelper.close();
    comparedatabase.close();
    }




}
```

Primeiro Produto Activity

```
package produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.Activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.DAO.ProdutoDAO;
import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.Model.Produto;
import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.R;
import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.util.SystemUiHider;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class PrimeiroProduto extends Activity {

    private EditText edt_produto;
    private EditText edt_preco;
    private EditText edt_unidade;
    private EditText edt_quantidade;
    private Button btn_proximo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_primeiro_produto);

    edt_produto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_produto1);
    edt_preco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_preco1);
    edt_unidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_unidade1);
    edt_quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_quantidade1);
    btn_proximo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Proximo);

    btn_proximo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Produto mproduto = new Produto();
            mproduto.setDesricao(edt_produto.getText().toString());
            mproduto.setPreco(edt_preco.getText().toString());
            mproduto.setUnidade(edt_unidade.getText().toString());
            mproduto.setQuantidade(edt_quantidade.getText().toString());

            final ProdutoDAO pDAO = new ProdutoDAO(getBaseContext());
            if (pDAO.salvarProduto(mproduto)) {
                Log.i("banco", "Produto salvo", null);
                AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrimeiroProduto.this);
                msg.setMessage("Ir para o proximo Produto");
                msg.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SegundoProduto.class).putExtra("id", pDAO.ultimoProduto()));
                    }
                });
                msg.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
                msg.show();
            }
        }
    });


    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.

    }
}
```

Segundo Produto Avtivity

```
package produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.Activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.DAO.ProdutoDAO;
import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.Model.Produto;
import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.R;
import produtos.compara.souza.hugo.comparaprodutos.util.SystemUiHider;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class SegundoProduto extends Activity {

    private EditText edt_produto2;
    private EditText edt_preco2;
    private EditText edt_unidade2;
    private EditText edt_quantidade2;
    private Button btn_compare;

    private Produto mProduto2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_segundo_produto);

    edt_produto2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_produto2);
    edt_preco2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_preco2);
    edt_unidade2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_unidade2);
    edt_quantidade2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_quantidade2);
    btn_compare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Compare);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Integer ID = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);

    final ProdutoDAO pDAO = new ProdutoDAO(getBaseContext());
    final Produto mProduto1 = pDAO.buscarProdutobyID(ID);

    mProduto2 = new Produto();

    mProduto2.setDesricao(edt_produto2.getText().toString());
    mProduto2.setPreco(edt_preco2.getText().toString());
    mProduto2.setUnidade(edt_unidade2.getText().toString());
    mProduto2.setQuantidade(edt_quantidade2.getText().toString());

    pDAO.salvarProduto(mProduto2);

    btn_compare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int[] arrayIDs = new int[2];
                arrayIDs[0] = mProduto1.getId_prod();
                arrayIDs[1] = pDAO.ultimoProduto();
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Compare_Activity.class).putExtra("ids", arrayIDs));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("meuapp", "Erro do Try Catch: " + e.getMessage().toString());
            }

        }
    });





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está guardando no objeto `mProduto2` o conteúdo dos campos `EditText` vazios e salvando esses valores no banco antes que você chegue a digitá-los.

Para corrigir isso, troque este trecho...

```
mProduto2 = new Produto();

mProduto2.setDesricao(edt_produto2.getText().toString());
mProduto2.setPreco(edt_preco2.getText().toString());
mProduto2.setUnidade(edt_unidade2.getText().toString());
mProduto2.setQuantidade(edt_quantidade2.getText().toString());

pDAO.salvarProduto(mProduto2);

btn_compare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            int[] arrayIDs = new int[2];
            arrayIDs[0] = mProduto1.getId_prod();
            arrayIDs[1] = pDAO.ultimoProduto();
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Compare_Activity.class).putExtra("ids", arrayIDs));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("meuapp", "Erro do Try Catch: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }
});
```

...por este:

```
mProduto2 = new Produto();

btn_compare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mProduto2.setDesricao(edt_produto2.getText().toString());
        mProduto2.setPreco(edt_preco2.getText().toString());
        mProduto2.setUnidade(edt_unidade2.getText().toString());
        mProduto2.setQuantidade(edt_quantidade2.getText().toString());

        pDAO.salvarProduto(mProduto2);

        try {
            int[] arrayIDs = new int[2];
            arrayIDs[0] = mProduto1.getId_prod();
            arrayIDs[1] = pDAO.ultimoProduto();
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Compare_Activity.class).putExtra("ids", arrayIDs));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("meuapp", "Erro do Try Catch: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.

Comment: Ok. Quando aceitar uma resposta, aproveite também para votar +1 nela.

Comment: eu tentei mas não deixa, fala q eu tenho que ter não sei quantos pontos ou algo assim